# Is there a common/standard/accepted way to model GPS entities (waypoints, tracks)?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, gps, data-modeling

This question somewhat overlaps knowledge on geospatial information systems, but I think it belongs here rather than GIS.StackExchange

There are a lot of applications around that deal with GPS data with very similar objects, most of them defined by the [GPX standard](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/). These objects would be collections of routes, tracks, waypoints, and so on. Some important programs, like GoogleMaps, serialize more or less the same entities in KML format. There are a lot of other mapping applications online (ridewithgps, strava, runkeeper, to name a few) which treat this kind of data in a different way, yet allow for more or less equivalent "operations" with the data. Examples of these operations are:

- Direct manipulation of tracks/trackpoints with the mouse (including drawing over a map);
- Merging and splitting based on time and/or distance;
- Replacing GPS-collected elevation with DEM/SRTM elevation;
- Calculating properties of part of a track (total ascent, average speed, distance, time elapsed);

There are some small libraries (like [GpxPy](https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/blob/master/gpxpy/gpx.py)) that try to model these objects AND THEIR METHODS, in a way that would ideally allow for an encapsulated, possibly language-independent Library/API.

The fact is: this problem is around long enough to allow for a "common accepted standard" to emerge, isn't it? In the other hand, most GIS software is very professionally oriented towards geospatial analyses, topographic and cartographic applications, while the typical trip-logging and trip-planning applications seem to be more consumer-hobbyist oriented, which might explain the quite disperse way the different projects/apps treat and model the problem.

Thus considering everything said, the question is: Is there, at present or being planned, a standard way to model canonicaly, in an Object-Oriented way, the most used GPS/Tracklog entities and their canonical attributes and methods?

There is the GPX schema and it is very close to what I imagine, but it only contains objects and attributes, not methods.

Any information will be very much appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Why would you replace GPS elevation with SRTM?

Comment: @Seth This is a fairly common operation, present in some desktop and online applications. Sometimes, due to reception factors (sky visibility, weather, foliage, interference) the elevation as registered is much less reliable than the (publicly available) Digital Elevation Model (DEM) of the track. Besides, sometimes you draw a track by hand, so your trackpoints don't have an elevation yet and you then insert them using some elevation service, like Google Elevation API for example.

Comment: That makes sense, I was thinking that you were replacing satellite-acquired elevation with SRTM.

Comment: @Seth At least one web service (STRAVA) somehow detects bad elevation reception in a track, and offers the option to replace it with DEM data.

Comment: I asked a similar question on the GIS StackExchange. No best answer, but some useful leads: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23464/is-there-a-good-gps-track-analysis-library

Comment: @Nelson Your linked question translates my feelings like a mirror. When I have some news I'll try to contact you from your blog! Also, there is a nice discussion going on in the RideWithGPS customer support forum: https://ridewithgps.zendesk.com/forums/21035931-feature-requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no standard library, interface, or even set of established best practices when it comes to storing/manipulating/processing "route" data. We have put a lot of effort into these problems at Ride with GPS and I know the same could be said by the other sites that solve related problems.  I wish there was a standard, and would love to work with someone on one.

GPX is OK and appears to be a sort-of standard... at least until you start processing GPX files and discover everyone has simultaneously added their own custom extensions to the format to deal with data like heart rate, cadence, power, etc.  Also, there isn't a standard way of associating a route point with a track point.  Your "bread crumb trail" of the route is represented as a series of trkpt elements, and course points (e.g. "turn left onto 4th street") are represented in a separate series of rtept elements. Ideally you want to associate a given course point with a specific track point, rather than just giving the course point a latitude and longitude.  If your path does several loops over the same streets, it can introduce some ambiguity in where the course points should be attached along the route.

KML and Garmin's TCX format are similar to GPX, with their own pros and cons.  In the end these formats really only serve the purpose of transferring the data between programs. They do not address the issue of how to represent the data in your program, or what type of operations can be performed on the data.

We store our track data as an array of objects, with keys corresponding to different attributes such as latitude, longitude, elevation, time from start, distance from start, speed, heart rate, etc. Additionally we store some metadata along the route to specify details about each section.  When parsing our array of track points, we use this metadata to split a Route into a series of Segments. Segments can be split, joined, removed, attached, reversed, etc.  They also encapsulate the method of trackpoint generation, whether that is by interpolating points along a straight line, or requesting a path representing directions between the endpoints.  These methods allow a reasonably straightforward implementation of drag/drop editing and other common manipulations. The Route object can be used to handle operations involving multiple segments.  One example is if you have a route composed of segments - some driving directions, straight lines, walking directions, whatever - and want to reverse the route. You can ask each segment to reverse itself, maintaining its settings in the process. At a higher level we use a Map class to wire up the interface, dispatch commands to the Route(s), and keep a series of snapshots or transition functions updated properly for sensible undo/redo support.

Route manipulation and generation is one of the goals.  The others are aggregating summary statistics are structuring the data for efficient visualization/interaction.  These problems have been solved to some degree by any system that will take in data and produce a line graph.  Not exactly new territory here.  One interesting characteristic of route data is that you will often have two variables to choose from for your x-axis: time from start, and distance from start. Both are monotonically increasing, and both offer useful but different interpretations of the data.  Looking at the a graph of elevation with an x-axis of distance will show a bike ride going up and down a hill as symmetrical.  Using an x-axis of time, the uphill portion is considerably wider.  This isn't just about visualizing the data on a graph, it also translates to decisions you make when processing the data into summary statistics.  Some weighted averages make sense to base off of time, some off of distance. The operations you end up wanting are min, max, weighted (based on your choice of independent var) average, the ability to filter points and perform a filtered min/max/avg (only use points where you were moving, ignore outliers, etc), different smoothing functions (to aid in calculating total elevation gain for example), a basic concept of map/reduce functionality (how much time did I spend between 20-30mph, etc), and fixed window moving averages that involve some interpolation. The latter is necessary if you want to identify your fastest 10 minutes, or 10 minutes of highest average heartrate, etc.  Lastly, you're going to want an easy and efficient way to perform whatever calculations you're running on subsets of your trackpoints.

You can see an example of all of this in action here if you're interested: http://ridewithgps.com/trips/964148

The graph at the bottom can be moused over, drag-select to zoom in.  The x-axis has a link to switch between distance/time.  On the left sidebar at the bottom you'll see best 30 and 60 second efforts - those are done with fixed window moving averages with interpolation.  On the right sidebar, click the "Metrics" tab.  Drag-select to zoom in on a section on the graph, and you will see all of the metrics update to reflect your selection.

Happy to answer any questions, or work with anyone on some sort of standard or open implementation of some of these ideas.

This probably isn't quite the answer you were looking for but figured I would offer up some details about how we do things at Ride with GPS since we are not aware of any real standards like you seem to be looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: It is important to mention to you, being me a die-hard biker who started bike trekking with paper maps drawn by hand over topo (usgs-like) maps, then taking the "route" through GPS-assisted rides then Google Earth then Google Maps assisted rides (with directions created via script), that your work with RideWithGPS is simply GROUNDBREAKING. Nothing currently available can beat its coprehensive features. Bikers are loving it as can be seen here: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/12777/2355

Comment: Also, this question pretty much translates my feelings, and I believe it translates yours, too. The guy who posted it might be a good fellow to talk about: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/23464/8254

Comment: Awesome thanks for the link, I will comment over there. We also do our own custom thing for reading elevation quickly from DEMs (for both route planning and replacing elevations in rides with bad data).  The only issue with a library is having to settle on a language. We are using Javascript for most of our stuff because it can run in the browser, and we can also run the same codebase on the server to ensure we get the same results for things like average speed, total distance, etc (all those summary statistics).

Comment: I imagined you'd use Javascript (I use Python). The latest agreement I did with myself is to create a language independent GPS_Objects API (currently for personal use, I plan to GitHub it in the future). Then, `Track.simplify(tolerance)` or `Track.join_tracksegments()` would have exactely the same signature and the same effects either when called in Python or in Javascript or whatever. Then, the (ideal, platonic, canonical) API could be programmed INTO any OO language, not IN some arbitrary language.

Comment: I think that sounds great.  I'd love to participate in some way even if you just want someone to bounce ideas off of or get feedback from.  My github is zackham and email is zack@ridewithgps.com

Comment: I have found some interesting stuff about normative documents published by ISO, take a look at my answer!

Answer (score 1):

After some deeper research, I feel obligated, for the record and for the help of future people looking for this, to mention the pretty much exhaustive work on the subject done by two entities, sometimes working in conjunction: ISO and OGC.

From ISO (International Standards Organization), the "[TC 211  - Geographic information/Geomatics](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_tc_browse.htm?commid=54904)" section pretty much contains it all.

From OGS (Open Geospatial Consortium), their [Abstract Specifications](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/as) are very extensive, being at the same time redundant and complimentary to ISO's.

I'm not sure it contains object methods related to the proposed application (gps track and waypoint analysis and manipulation), but for sure the core concepts contained in these documents is rather solid. UML is their schema representation of choice.

---

**ISO 6709** "[...] specifies the representation of coordinates, including latitude and longitude, to be used in data interchange. It additionally specifies representation of horizontal point location using coordinate types other than latitude and longitude. It also specifies the representation of height and depth that can be associated with horizontal coordinates. Representation includes units of measure and coordinate order."

**ISO 19107** "specifies conceptual schemas for describing the spatial characteristics of geographic features, and a set of spatial operations consistent with these schemas. It treats vector geometry and topology up to three dimensions. It defines standard spatial operations for use in access, query, management, processing, and data exchange of geographic information for spatial (geometric and topological) objects of up to three topological dimensions embedded in coordinate spaces of up to three axes."

---

If I find something new, I'll come back to edit this, including links when available.